# Alignment / Trim of Notes in Figure Environment

Tags: floats, alignment, notes

I would like to have notes under a figure that are well aligned to the left and right corner of figure. In my case the notes are too wide and go further to the left and right than the figure. How to I get each line of the notes to start at the left corner of the figure and end at the right corner of the figure. Also is there really nothing similar to threeparttable for figures that have notes embedded? Here is my code:

`\begin{figure}[h!]`

`\centering`

`\caption{Caption of the Example Figure}`

`\includegraphics[scale=1]{example figure}`

`\subcaption*{\scriptsize \textit{Notes:}`
`These are figure notes that go too far to the left and right of the figure. I would like each line of the notes to start at the left corner of the figure and end at the right corner of the figure.}`

`\end{figure}`

Comment: `threeparttable` aloso offers the `measurefigure` environment. The documentation, however, warns: "It is fairly fragile though, and should be used only for a single graphic above a single caption."

Comment: Can you please provide a working example with `measurefigure`. I am not sure how it works.